# How to paste multiple columns under one column?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```js
function writeData () {
   var sss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   //var inSheet2 = sss.getSheetByName('Copy of 01-Raw Data 2');
   var inSheet2 = sss.getSheets()[4];
   var input2 = inSheet2.getRange(2, 1, inSheet2.getLastRow(),42);
   var outSheet1 = sss.getSheets()[0];
   var outStartRow2 = outSheet1.getLastRow() + 2;
   var outStartRow3 = outSheet1.getLastRow() + 2;
   input2.copyFormatToRange(outSheet1, 2, 42, outStartRow3, outStartRow2);                                

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var inSheet = sss.getSheets()[0];
   var input = inSheet.getRange(2, 18, inSheet.getLastRow(), 42).getValues();
   var outSheet2 = sss.getSheets()[4];
   var outStartRow = outSheet2.getLastRow() + 1;
   for (var col = 0; col < input.length; col++) { 
   for (var row = 0; row < input[col].length; row++) {
  outSheet2.getRange(outStartRow + row, col + 5)
  .setValue(input[col][row]);
   }
   }
  }
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Write data", functionName: "writeData"});
  ss.addMenu("Custom functions", menuEntries);
}
```

I am using google-apps-script in Google spreadsheets.

What i have:

[image]

What I want to achieve:

[image]

Please,  let me know if you got a way to make this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh0=ss.getSheetByName('INPUT');
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('OUTPUT');
  var rg0=sh0.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg0.getValues();
  var oA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
     for(var j=0;j<vA[0].length;j++)  
     {
       if(vA[j][i])
       {
          oA.push([vA[j][i]]);
       }
       else
       {
          for(var k=0;k<j;k++)
          {
             oA.pop(); 
          }
         break;
       }
     }
  }
  sh1.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Data Sheet:

[image]

Output Sheet:

[image]